# What is the benefit of using Serde::Serialize/Deserialize on defined types?

Tags: pallet, runtime, kitties-tutorial

As an example, in the Kitties tutorial :

```
#[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, PartialEq, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Serialize, Deserialize))]
pub enum Gender {
    Male,
    Female,
}
```

Why do we use Serialize and Deserialize given that the implementations are not compiled when building the WASM runtime?

Comment: I can give short answer on that. The substrate runtime is compiled in native and wasm, and also if u remove serder and just use parity scale codec its just works fine. And honestly no need to use serde

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use serde for exporting/importing the `GenesisConfig`. So, if you want to use something as part of the `GenesisConfig` of your pallet you need to derive `Serialize`/`Deserialize`.

Comment: For more info, see the expansion of the implementation of the construct_runtime macro that deals with the config:
https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/support/procedural/src/construct_runtime/expand/config.rs#L67. You can see that the overarching Config (aggregation of all pallet configs) implements serialize + deserialize, therefore its fields must also.